# How to use timer for for next loop in visual basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have a case where i need to generate millions of unique codes. For this I have created a generate function where the random number is generated. I call this function from a for loop and add the generated number on a list box. my code is as follow

```
  for i=1 to val(txtnumber.txt)
       mynum=generate()
  next
```

I have created a lable on form where i wanted to display the no of secs elapsed while processing the loop. I used timer control as

```
     timer1.start()
     for i=1 to val(txtnumber.text)
        mynum=generate()
        listbox1.items.add(mynum)
     next
     timer1.stop
```

and on timer1_tick function

```
     Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Val(Label1.Text) + 1
     End Sub
```

but when i click generate button, all numbers are generated, but timer doesnot shows time elapsed.

I may have missed something, so please help me out

Comment: First, take a look at these links: [Globally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) and [Guid Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx).

Comment: @RandyDodson I read about guid and can understand it is used for unique identifier, but how this is linked to my timer code. This I am not able to understand.

Comment: I've tested your code; the timer never fires. It appears that you are trying to do threading without threading. What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably best handled in a BackgroundWorker.  Place one on the form and set its `WorkerReportsProgress=True`.  Also, placing a million numbers in a ListBox probably isn't a good idea, so I omitted that.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Button1.Enabled = False
  BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
  Dim started As DateTime = Now
  For i As Integer = 1 To val(txtnumber.txt)
    mynum=generate()
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, Nothing)
  Next
  Dim ended As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(started)
  BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, ended.TotalSeconds.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
  If e.UserState IsNot Nothing Then
    Label1.Text = e.UserState.ToString()
  Else
    Label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
  Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Your label should be updating correctly when the worker reports the `ProgressChanged` event.

Comment: This worked for me!!! backgroundprocessworker was totally lost from my mind. Thank you very much. I also agreed your idea not to list generated numbers on listbox so, please suggest me how I could save the generated numbers.

Comment: @Prajwal To a file or database I would guess.  It's hard to answer since I don't know the purpose of generating a million keys.

Answer (score 1):

What you're encountering is a threading issue.  The work you are doing to generate the numbers is being executing by the UI thread, so it never gets a chance to update the screen.  Take a look here:  [How to prevent UI from freezing during lengthy process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2447123/475820)

This one might also have good information for you:  [Updating UI from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8498937/475820)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private _Counter As Integer = 0
Private _StartTime As Date = Now

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    _StartTime = Now
    _Counter = CInt(Val(txtnumber.Text))
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Label1.Text = "0"
    Timer1.Interval = 50
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ListBox1.Items.Add(generate())
    Label1.Text = New Date((Now - _StartTime).Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss.ff")
    _Counter -= 1
    If (_Counter <= 0) Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Or you can research actual [Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kac2kdh.aspx).

Comment: for now I tried your code but i was not able to calculate actual time required to generate the 1000 codes,

Comment: I modified my example to display elapsed time in the label. Also, the interval of the timer will effect the time required to create the values.